# Percent composition by volume of the reaction H2 + Br2 <=> 2HBr

Tags: equilibrium, concentration, stoichiometry

> For the reaction $\ce{H2(g) + Br2(g) <=> 2HBr(g)}$ at a certain temperature, $K=1$. Determine the composition (in per cent by volume) of the equilibrium reaction mixture if the initial mixture consisted of $3$ moles of $\ce{H2}$ and $2$ moles of $\ce{Br2}$.

The answer given is $49.6\%$ of $\ce{H2}$, $29.6\%$ $\ce{Br2}$, $20.8\%$ $\ce{HBr}$.

I made an ICE table with following data:

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
   *        & \mathbf I   & \mathbf C   & \mathbf E \\
\hline
 \ce{H2}    & 3   & -x  & 3-x \\
 \ce{Br2}   & 2   & -x  & 2-x \\
 \ce{HBr}   & 0   & 2x  & 2x \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Using this data I made the equation:

$$
1=\frac{4x^2}{(3-x)(2-x)}
$$

My work in solving it was:

$$
(3-x)(2-x)=4x^2 \\
3x^2+5x-6=0 \\
x=\frac{-5+9.85}{6}\text{ or } x=\frac{-5-9.85}{6}
$$

I used the answer $0.808$ for $x$. I calculated the volume percents as:

$$
\%~\ce{H2} = {3-x\over 5} = 43.84\% \\
\%~\ce{Br2} = {2-x\over 5} = 23.84\% \\
\%~\ce{HBr} = {2x\over 5} = 32.33\%
$$

But, these don't match the answer given. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: There's a few spelling mistakes

Comment: What equation did you use for the equilibrium expression? You should have gotten a quadratic equation, not a linear one.

Comment: I got  quadratic equation but squared x are canceled each other

Comment: Please see my edits (click "edited just now") for examples of how to mark up your posts.

Comment: The $x^2$ terms should not have cancelled. Aside from the typo in the initial $\ce{HBr}$ column, your ICE table looks correct to me. Please add to your post the equilibrium expression you used to make the equation $6-3x-2x=0$.  See [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88#88) for details of how to format equations, if needed.

Comment: Hmm. I get a different answer than the one given. Can you add into the question the volume percents that you calculated in your work?

Comment: Br:23.84%    H: 43.84%  Hbr:32.32%

Comment: This is problem from chemistry exercises book, N.L. Glinka, the problem #353

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation and your math appear correct to me: I also get $x=0.808$ from the quadratic equation, and calculate the same percentages.

As long as you are supposed to assume [ideal gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas) behavior in the question, it appears to me that the answer key is incorrect.